# I/flutter ( 5706): Error: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?'

Tags: flutter

I had developed an application for tracking shipments that when I updated the flutter version it stopped working so I had to start over.
In the module that creates the users I am getting an error that I have not been able to solve. I appreciate if someone can help me.
I use a provider and a model.
The mistake is:

I/flutter ( 5706): Error: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?'
I/flutter ( 5706): Respuesta: null

My register controller

```
    class RegisterController {

  BuildContext? context;
  TextEditingController userController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lastnameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController confirmPasswordController = new TextEditingController();

  UsersProvider usersProvider = UsersProvider();

  Future? init(BuildContext context){
    this.context = context;
    usersProvider.init(context);
    return null;
  }

  void register() async {
    String username = userController.text.trim();
    String name = nameController.text.trim();
    String lastname = lastnameController.text.trim();
    String password = passwordController.text.trim();
    String confirmPassword = confirmPasswordController.text.trim();

    User user = new User(
        username: username,
        name: name,
        lastname: lastname,
        password: password
    );

    ResponseApi? responseApi = await usersProvider.create(user);

    print('Respuesta: ${responseApi?.toJson()}');

    print(username);
    print(name);
    print(lastname);
    print(password);
    print(confirmPassword);
  }

}
```

Users provider

```
class UsersProvider {

  String _url = Environment.API_DELIVERY;
  String _api = '/api/users';

  BuildContext? context;

  Future? init(BuildContext context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  Future<ResponseApi?> create(User user) async {

    try {
      Uri url = Uri.http(_url, '$_api/create');
      String bodyParams = json.encode(user);
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      };
      final response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: bodyParams);
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      ResponseApi responseApi = ResponseApi.fromJson(data);
      return responseApi;
    } catch(e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      return null;
    }

  }

}
```

User model

```
User userFromJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userToJson(User data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class User {

  String? id;
  String username;
  String name;
  String lastname;
  String password;
  String? sessionToken;
  String? image;

  User({
    this.id,
    required this.username,
    required this.name,
    required this.lastname,
    required this.password,
    this.sessionToken,
    this.image,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
    id: json["id"] is int ? json["id"].toString() : json["id"],
    username: json["username"],
    name: json["name"],
    lastname: json["lastname"],
    password: json["password"],
    sessionToken: json["session_token"] ?? "",
    image: json["image"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "username": username,
    "name": name,
    "lastname": lastname,
    "password": password,
    "session_token": sessionToken,
    "image": image,
  };
}
```

Comment: Please add line number as well for this error

Comment: Add stack trace of exception